# .net 4.5 Asp Mvc -> Error 403.14- IIS 7 - Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2008-r2, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

When I want to deploy an MVC 4 (.net 4.5) application to my iis i got the 403.14 calling me that the content ist not browseable.

This also occurs when i deploy the unchanged mvc 4 template.

when using the mvc 4 template with .net 4.0 everything works.
I checked the other posts but can't figure out the solution.

ist set

i ran aspnet_regiss -i which completed without any errors.

the only strange thing is that .net 4.5 is installed in the .net 4.0 directory %windows%/microsoft.net/Framework64/**4.0.30319**
From this folder i also ran aspnet_regiis.

to ensure that 4.5 is installed i restarted the .net 4.5 setup and it tells me taht it is installes

Also the apppools show me **4.0.30319** as version.

There is an other application targeting mvc with 4.5  which runs. but i don't know wether it was created with a 4.0 templated and retargeted to 4.5
Any hints?

The app.config is the unchanged default from the mvc 4 template.

I just tested to create a subfolder which i convert to an application. placing the site there makes it working for the main page. But all subpages forexample login end ab in a 404 Not Found

But why not on root folder?

Comment: 403.14 means "Directory listing denied." follow KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942062

Comment: It's an MVC app so there is no default document. The routes should get interpreted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.net 4.5 replaces .net 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx.
You probably want to use this in your web.config file to make you application work:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
...
</system.webServer>
```

If the code does what you want then you will want to do it the proper way as described here:
http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html