# How to expose more ports on a running docker container

Tags: docker, port

I have exposed port 3306 on my docker container, and I would like to install a web server on it and expose port 80 on the same container.

Comment: What have you already tried so far? Pls have a look at the docker documentation first. e.g. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Especially the EXPOSE Command in the Dockerfile and the -p option on docker run

Comment: @BoasEnkler People like you who act so rude with new members are the ones who ruin SO. You have a good reputation, but that doesn't mean everyone else is like you. I just went through your questions and saw this first question you asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540428/net-4-5-asp-mvc-error-403-14-iis-7-windows-server-2008-r2 Remember you were also the same when you began :) Peace! So next time when someone asks a question, don't be rude please :)

Comment: Sorry i didn't what to be rude. :-) Just wanted to point out that it is better to have a questions with more details, and examples as it just increases the number of replies :)

Comment: yeah, I did read through this part, however personally I hate to use iptable. I was thinking whether there is a easier way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can actually expose more port as the container is running, you'll have to recreate it and expose all of your ports

Comment: How to do it during restart ?

Comment: You have to do a `docker stop` and then a `docker start` with all the -p options, you might also want to rebuild your image with multiples `EXPOSE` commands. It would be easier for me to help you if you could link your Dockerfile.

You should not lose any data since you should be using volume for storage.

Comment: unknown shorthand flag: 'p' in -p when I try to use -p option

Comment: And it's `docker run`, not `docker start`. You can also delete the old container with `docker rm`